# JQuery AJAX request stuck pending indefinetely

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use `jQuery.ajax({})` to run a PHP file. All my ajax requests will not execute and just remain pending forever.

I have looked at many different solutions but none have worked.

```
    let account= [{email: null, pass: null, accountType: null}]
    function logIn() {
    account.email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
        account.pass = document.getElementById("passwordinput").value;
    if(account.email.substring(0,1) === '1'){
        account.accountType = "student";
    } else if (account.email === ''/* admin email*/) {
        account.accountType = "super";
    } else {
        account.accountType = "teacher";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"logIn.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            email: account.email,
            password: account.pass,
            accountType : account.accountType
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}
```

above my code just grabs user input from `<input>` fields in HTML. then figures out an accountType and tries to run the ajax file. When I debug the program the ajax statement does nothing at all. the php file doesn't even run one line. I don't know what is stopping the requests from working. This happens on Firefox and Chrome.

PHP file for reference:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "mentorDB");
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$accType = $_POST['accountType'];

if ($accType == 'student') {
    $query = "SELECT `student_email`, `user_pass` FROM `students` WHERE `student_email` LIKE ? AND `user_pass` LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    if ($stmt === false) {
        die('Error preparing query: ' . $conn->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //Fetch result rows as associative arrays
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);

    $conn->close();
} elseif ($accType == 'teacher') {
    $query = "SELECT `teacher_email`, `user_pass` FROM `teachers` WHERE `teacher_email` LIKE ? AND `user_pass` LIKE ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        die('Error preparing query: ' . $conn->error);
    }

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //Fetch result rows as associative arrays
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Here is what the network console looks like:
[pending network request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mHZk.png)

Mostly just wondering if there is something in my JS code that is making the ajax request stay pending forever.

Sorry if this code is no good I'm in high school and it's all new to me.

Comment: Look in the network console for issues after turning on error reporting in your PHP

Comment: Are you actually calling your `logIn()` function somewhere?

Comment: @brombeer yes, in my HTML file I have a button that calls it onclick

Comment: "the php file doesn't even run one line" -- how do you know?

Comment: @soulseekah I just echo a test string at the top of the file to check. nothing happens, and the network request doesn't complete

Comment: You appear to be storing passwords in plain text form rather than as hashes - you should  investigate `password_hash` and `password_verify`

Comment: add an `error:` callback - `I have looked at many different solutions` did any mention the `error:` callback?

Comment: check file name and location of login.php. is it present in correct folder and does it execute properly when you call the ajax function.

Comment: @nfh66 That does not at all necessarily mean it didn't run, though. What happens if you directly access logIn.php in the browser?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The passwords will be hashed but it's easier not to right now, and I'm not working with real users data

Comment: @soulseekah it's interesting the behavior it has, in chrome the page loads forever, but if I run it on my pc it does run. The issue seems to lie in the communication between my JS and PHP.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki it's in the same folder and I don't think it fully executes, look at the photo from the post and you'll see it never executes, and just stays pending the whole time.

Comment: please provide headers, payload information in the ajax request.

Comment: There is a closing curly bracket missing in your javascript. Place one "}" after the ajax call.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki the curly bracket didn't make it into my post but is there in my JS, i'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

Started my computer the next morning and the everything works! Weird cause I did restart it before.

Comment: you can close the question if you wish